# Align button text top left

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How to make the button text top left in the below case (div2).

I have to use button for some requirement, but make it look like a normal text. Any help you help.

Container is flexbox column and have a button with flex 1.

I don't want add an element inside button and make it position absolute.

Need cleaner way.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.div1, .div3 {
  height: 40px;
}
.div2 {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="div1">
     div1
   </div>
   <button class="div2">
     I want this text to be top left
   </button>
   <div class="div3">
     div3
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"Align button text top left"_ _"make the button text center"_ - well which is it that you want?

Answer (score 2):

**Top left Alignment**

Use the property `flex-direction: column;` to align your text top left.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.div1, .div3 {
  height: 40px;
}
.div2 {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: left;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="div1">
     div1
   </div>
   <button class="div2">
     I want this text to be top left
   </button>
   <div class="div3">
     div3
   </div>
</div>
```

**Center Alignment**

Just change your style `text-align:left` to `text-align:center`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.div1, .div3 {
  height: 40px;
}
.div2 {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="div1">
     div1
   </div>
   <button class="div2">
     I want this text to be top left
   </button>
   <div class="div3">
     div3
   </div>
</div>
```

You can do the combination and apply the properties as per your requirements.

Comment: While this works in most browsers. Our favorite browser Internet Explorer 11 doesn't support it. :-/

Answer (score 2):

This is not perfect and probably you will have to play around with this but i guess this is a step in the right direction.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.div1, .div3 {
  height: 40px;
}
.div2 {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: left;
  position:absolute;
flex-direction: column;

    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49028282/align-button-text-top-left#comment86347372_49028528

Answer (score 2):

So, I added padding-bottom to the .div2 classed element, so the text inside div2 is pushed up and away from the bottom edge of the element.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.div1, .div3 {
  height: 40px;
}
.div2 {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: left;
  padding-bottom: 40%; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="div1">
     div1
   </div>
   <button class="div2">
     I want this text to be top left
   </button>
   <div class="div3">
     div3
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I am member of Stackoverflow since  1 hour ago, so anything that helps me getting better orientation and future contributions is great. Thanks.

Comment: Well, welcome to Stackoverflow then, Wlodzimierz! I recommend reading [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and the other [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) articles as a good starting point. Have a good time here on SO.

Comment: padding-bottom cannot be solution for this. It effects when the height has been changed.